# Access default state in Pinia

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, pinia

I am trying to migrate from Vuex to Pinia and I couldn't figure out what `defaultStateFactory()` equivalent is in Pinia.

Here is an mutation from Vuex. I want to convert this to Pinia.

```js
setOperatedAddress(state, payload) {
  if (payload) {
    Object.assign(state.operatedAddress, payload)
  } else {
    Object.assign(state.operatedAddress, defaultStateFactory().operatedAddress)
  }
}
```

If no address provided I want operated address to fall back to initial empty state.

Comment: There is no `defaultStateFactory` function in official Vuex API. Isn't it just a custom function used as a `state` [option when creating the store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#state) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply by defining your `state` function externally, and use it both in the store definition and inside your actions. Something like this:

```js
const defaultStateFactory = () => {
  return {
    operatedAddress: 'foo'
  }
}

const myStore = defineStore('myStore', {
  state: defaultStateFactory,
  actions: {
    setOperatedAddress(payload) {
      this.operatedAddress = payload ?? defaultStateFactory().operatedAddress
    }
  },
})
```